# My edit button changes all my groups in the views

Tags: vue.js

Here is the view of my page groups and when I click on the test edit button for example it will change that test in backend, but on the view it changes all groups. 
I add 2 photos of my views one or I do not click and one or I click on the test button edit
[image]

[image]

code of the page :

template :

```
    <template>
  <v-container fluid grid-list-md>
    <v-data-iterator
      :items="groups"
      :items-per-page.sync="itemsPerPage"
      :footer-props="{ itemsPerPageOptions }"
    >
      <template v-slot:default="props">
        <v-layout wrap>
          <v-flex v-for="group in groups" :key="group.id" xs12 sm6 md4 lg3>
            <v-card>
              <v-card-title
                ><h4>{{ group.name }}</h4>
                <v-btn
                  class="mx-2"
                  fab
                  dark
                  small
                  color="orange"
                  @click="editGroup(group)"
                >
                  <v-icon dark>edit</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
                <v-btn
                  class="mx-2"
                  fab
                  dark
                  small
                  color="red"
                  @click="deleteGroup(group)"
                >
                  <v-icon dark>remove</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
              </v-card-title>
              <v-divider></v-divider>

              <groupsMembers :members="group.members" :editItem="edit" />

              <v-form ref="form" v-if="edit">
                <v-text-field
                  v-model="member.email"
                  :counter="15"
                  label="Email du membre"
                  required
                ></v-text-field>
                <v-btn color="success" class="mr-4" @click="validate(group)">
                  Ajouter un nouveau membre
                </v-btn>
              </v-form>
            </v-card>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </template>
    </v-data-iterator>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

javascripts :

```
<script>
import groupsMembers from "./groupsMembers";
export default {
  props: {
    groups: Array
  },
  components: {
    groupsMembers
  },
  data: () => ({
    edit: false,
    itemsPerPageOptions: [4, 8, 12],
    itemsPerPage: 4,
    member: {
      email: "",
      groupId: 0,
      registerToSeances: true
    }
  }),
  methods: {
    validate(group) {
      this.member.groupId = group.id;
      this.$store.dispatch("groups/addMember", this.member);
    },
    editGroup(group) {
      console.log("groups", group);
      this.edit = !this.edit;
    },
    deleteGroup(group) {
      this.$store.dispatch("groups/deleteGroup", group);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I do not know where it could be

Answer (score 0):

You have a single `edit` field used to control the visibility of all the `v-btn` instances.

To control each one separately you need to move this field into the `groups` (or have a parallel collection).

A simple first step:

- Change `edit` to be an array.
- Change references to `edit` to `edit[id]` (where `id` is the id of the group as used by `:key`)

You might need to read `edit[id]` as `edit[id] || false` to avoid issues with `undefined`.

Comment: do you have an exemple ?

Comment: @NoPLZ I've sketched out an approach, but with only partial code I'm making assumptions.